# Symfony 4 Internal Server Error : Context visitingStack not working well

Tags: api, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, http-status-code-500

I am developing my rest api with symfony 4, after authentication and getting token I tried to request an endpoint which return logged in user 's information which it return 500 error whose message is:

```
"message": "Context visitingStack not working well",
                "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\Exception\\RuntimeException",
                "trace": [
                    {
                        "namespace": "",
                        "short_class": "",
                        "class": "",
                        "type": "",
                        "function": "",
                        "file": "/home/dev/soireesprivilege/api/vendor/jms/serializer/src/SerializationContext.php",
                        "line": 84,
                        "args": []
                    },
                    {
                        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
                        "short_class": "SerializationContext",
                        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\SerializationContext",
                        "type": "->",
                        "function": "stopVisiting",
                        "file": "/home/dev/soireesprivilege/api/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
                        "line": 199,
                        "args": [
                            [
                                "object",
                                "Doctrine\\ORM\\
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
```

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Do you have a OneToMany relationship on the Entity? It is best to exclude them from serialization as it could cause this error also. Use the `JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Exclude` to skip them during serialization.

Answer (score 4):

I've faced this issue today.

The problem I had is that I had a pending migration, so the entity I was trying to serialize wasn't created in the database.

Just a `bin/console make:migration` and `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` solved it.

It you are not using migrations use `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that you're having an extra fields in your entity.

Try changing exclusion policy to all and expose only entity fields using @Expose.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation AS JMS;

/**
* @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class Product
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @JMS\Expose()
 */
private $name;
```